# Arrival and departure probabilities in an Erlang Loss system

Tags: probability, markov-process, queueing-theory

Consider an M/G/c/c system; that is, an Erlang loss system with a general service time. If the system is in the steady state situation, what is the probability that a randomly observed event is an arrival? What is the probability that a randomly observed event is a departure?

I think the probabilities are 0.5. Is anyone aware of a reference about this problem that I can study?

Comment: Even if it were an $M/M/c/c$ system, the answer would depend on the parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$.  If service times are very small (so $\mu$ is large relative to $\lambda$) then there are almost no drops and so the time average departure rate $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} Departures(t)/t$ is almost the same as the arrival rate $\lambda$.  Conversely, if service times are large (small $\mu$) then there are lots of drops and so time average departure rate is much smaller than $\lambda$. Here I am assuming that a "departure" is a job that finishes service (not an arrival that is dropped).

Comment: Of course I am also assuming that every arrival is either dropped, or accepted (where accepted jobs eventually become departures).  If you define "arrival" only as those jobs that are accepted then the answer is different.  Anyhow, the long term departure rate is equal to the long term acceptance rate $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} D(t)/t = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} Accept(t)/t = \lambda_{accept}$ and $\lambda = \lambda_{accept} + \lambda_{drop}$.